# CodeIgniter - flash session deleting all session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using flash data for success/error messages.

I am experiencing issue: after I set flashdata - all session data are deleted but only in few controlers, in other controlers it is working properly.

Cotroller 1: (function whre it is working OK)

```
public function vymazat($id)
    {
        if(!is_numeric($id)) redirect();

        $this->admin_model->delete_coupon($id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Kupón bol úspešne vymazaný');
        redirect('admin/kupony/zobrazit');

    }
```

Controller 2: (function where it is not working)

```
public function vymazat($id)
{
    if(!is_numeric($id)) redirect();

    $this->admin_model->delete_order($id);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Kupón bol pridaný');
    redirect('admin/objednavky/zobrazit');

}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: comment redirect in both cases and put this `print_r($this->session->userdata());` and post results.

Comment: Problem solved, the problem was in charset of document. I had to use UTF8

Answer (score 0):

From CodeIgniter Documentation:

> CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be
>   available for the next server request, and are then automatically
>   cleared.

Your redirection may perhaps taking more than one request, thus results clearing your `flashdata`.

You can use the following:

```
//In your Redirected to, controller constructor
$this->session->keep_flashdata('message');
```

And see if the `flashdata` is displayed, if yes, then my above statement is correct.